# jQuery: Get original selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm in the middle of writing a plugin and I'd like to be able to get the original selector that jQuery used to create the object.

So if you wanted to apply something like `.siblings()` you could get all the siblings of that type, whether it looks up siblings of a certain class or siblings of a certain element type.

- `jQuery('div')` – `'div'`
- `jQuery(jQuery('div'))` – `'[jQuery] object' // would require recursively finding the selector of this`
- `jQuery('#elment')` – `'#element'`
- `jQuery('.class')` – `'.class'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just access the jQuery object's [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) property:

```
console.log($("div").selector); // 'div'
console.log($("#foo").selector); // '#foo'
```

Comment: are you kidding!?  I went into api.jquery.com and searched for selector and all it popped up was the "[ancestor descendant]" bs and typical jQuery("[selector]") nonsense... no help. -- thank you! - do you know where the documentation is on it?

Comment: @vol7ron - I don't think it is documented. Come to think of it, I can't remember how I discovered it.

Comment: unfortunately `jQuery('.className').each(function(){jQuery(this).selector});` returns an empty string;

Comment: You can see it in here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js Look in the function `init`. It has a line like this: `this.selector = selector;` if the selector is string. If the selector is on object with a selector property then it has this: `this.selector = selector.selector;` So it will even handle the "recursive" case

Comment: @vol7ron - that's because `jQuery(this)` constructs a jQuery object with a DOMElement instead of a selector.

Comment: right, I wish it would return objects for those cases, that I would be able to check.

Comment: I guess I would have to store the original object in a temp variable and call it on that? `var t=$('.cName'); t.each(function(){$(this).data('selector',t.selector)});` -- something to that effect

Comment: `.selector` property was deprecated in 1.7

Answer (score 7):

**This no longer seems possible**... '.selector' was removed in version 3 and jquery instead recommends passing in the selector twice.

https://api.jquery.com/selector/....

> The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting .live() in the jQuery Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version. **The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set.** Plugins that need to use a selector string within their plugin can require it as a parameter of the method. For example, a "foo" plugin could be written as $.fn.foo = function( selector, options ) { /* plugin code goes here */ };, and the person using the plugin would write $( "div.bar" ).foo( "div.bar", {dog: "bark"} ); **with the "div.bar" selector repeated as the first argument of .foo()**.

Comment: Good update -- looks like context + selector properties were dropped.  Curious how to incorporate this into the selected answer -- should it be added as a comment to that answer instead?

Comment: I just added a comment as well based on your feedback.  However, I'm hesitant to do that in place of a new answer since many (or at least me ;)) scan the answers well before digging into the individual comments.  If my answer holds to be correct, than eventually an "update" on the original answer would probably be a good idea.

Comment: That's what I feel too, I'm uncertain how to handle this for the different versions of jQuery

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to what Karim has put:

```
var t = jQuery('.clName');

t.each(function(){ 
   jQuery(this).data('selector',t.selector);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to refer to the root jQuery constructor from the DOM object, as you noted.  So I took it that caching the jQuery object was the only way. (I only made this an answer so I had it for future reference)